# accessing objects of window from selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am new to both selenium and javascript.
I want to load a javascript called VisualEvent to pages that opening in selenium controled browser. and then access to its variables from selenium in java.
First phase is done perfectly by below:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
String script = //Minified of below script
//////////////
(function() {
var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'file:' ? 'http:' : '';
var url = protocol + '//www.sprymedia.co.uk/VisualEvent/VisualEvent_Loader.js';
if (typeof VisualEvent != 'undefined') {
    if (VisualEvent.instance !== null) {
        VisualEvent.close();
    } else {
        new VisualEvent();
    }
} else {
    var n = document.createElement('script');
    n.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');
    n.setAttribute('src', url + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime());
    document.body.appendChild(n);
}
})();
///////////////////////
Object[] a = { null, null, null };
driver.executeScript(script, a);
```

But when i want to access `window.VisualEvent` :

```
script = "return window.VisualEvent.instance;";
Object b = driver.executeScript(script, a);
```

this execption is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: TypeError: window.VisualEvent is undefined
```

while when i execute this in same browser console i will get the reference.
Moreover, I have access to `winow.document` object from selenium.
Any idea?

Comment: You're not waiting for the script to finish downloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy Ray commented, the VisualEvent script did not loaded completely. So i resolved it by sleeping selenium Thread.